# "Improve" or "improves"

Tags: grammar

Last lesson I was struggling to decide which sentence is correct. Here they are:

> Your health and body improve while you walk outside.
> OR
> Your body and health improves while you walk outside.

I understand that following the rules of present simple tense it should be "improve" as "body and health" can be substituted by "they". However, that doesn't really sound natural to me. Please help and provide your explanation. I am completely confused.

Comment: Your health and body are two things and are therefore plural so they **improve**. It's completely natural.

Comment: Also, this isn't really a matter of "rules of present simple tense". It's a matter of subject-verb agreement. (The same issue appears in the present perfect.)

Answer (score 1):

As what @MichaelHarvey has mentioned, "health" and "body" are two things and are therefore plural so "they improve". It's completely natural.

You only use "improves" when using singular, as "improves" is in third-person singular simple present tense. E.g.

> My health improves when I exercise

In the above sentence, only "health" is being focused on, so you use "improves"